# DropDownList Asp.NET C# MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

A continuacion dejo las imagenes (1,2). Tengo la BD "Escuela" la cual tiene las tablas Alumno y Grupo, y quiero agregar un DropDownList el cual muestre los grupos que existan en la BD y seleccionarlo. Agradecería su ayuda.
[image: 1.Este es el controller que hasta ahorita tengo]

[image: 2. Es el formulario donde iría el DropDownList]

Answer (score 1):

Hay muchas maneras de hacerlo, lo más sencillo es mediante un ViewBag

Supongamos que tu tabla Grupo se compone de la siguiente manera.

En tu Controller.

```
ViewBag.Grupos= context.Grupos.Select(x => new { IdGrupo = x.Id, Grupo = x.Grupo}).ToList();
```

En tu vista lo asignas así.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedGrupoId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Grupos, "IdGrupo", "Grupo"), "- Selecciona uno -", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias! lo intentaré

Answer (score 0):

Para esto es recomendable el uso de **viewmodels** que nos permiten enviar un modelo personalizado a la vista.

**ViewModel**

```
// Este lo puedes usar para crear y etitar
public class AumnoEditViewModel
{
    public int GrupoId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Grupo> Grupos{ get; set; }

    // Incluir propiedades del alumno
    public AlumnoId { get; set; }
    public Nombre { get; set; } // Etc
}
```

**Controlador**

```
public class AlumnoController : Controller
{
    MyContext db = new MyContext();

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddOrEdit()
    {
       var model = new AlumnoEditViewModel();
       model.Grupos = db.Grupos.ToList();
       return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddOrEdit(AlumnoEditViewModel model)
    {
       var nuevoAlumno = new Alumno()
       {
           Nombre = model.Nombre,
           GrupoId = model.GrupoId // El Id del grupo seleccionado
       };
       db.Alumnos.Add(nuevoAlumno);
       db.SaveChanges();
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

**Vista**

```
@model TuProyecto.Models.AumnoEditViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrEdit", "Alumnos", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="Nombre">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="GrupoId">
            // Llenar las opciones del select
            @foreach (var grupo in Model.Grupos)
            {
               <option value="@grupo.Id">@grupo.Nombre</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
}
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: **muchas gracias!! fue de mucha ayuda**

Comment: @JesúsEduardoRicoSandoval marca la respuesta como aceptada, sólo tú puedes dar click en al check del costado de la respuesta. Saludos